# Can I implement an abstact method by a concrete method with a different name?

Tags: python, inheritance

i am experimenting with implementation of the monte-carlo-tree-search algorithm for the travelling salesman problem. In this context, I have created a class that without going into details looks somewhat like these:

```
class Position:

    def __init__(self, salesman, cities):
        self.salesman= salesman
        self.cities= cities

   def unvisited_cities(self):
       result = {}
       for name, city in self.cities.items():
            if city.not_visited():
                result[name] = city
       return result

    def travel_to_city(self, city_name):
        new_salesman = self.salesman.travel_to(city_name)
        return Position(new_salesman, self.cities)
```

Now, I want to declare this class as a child class for an abstact class:

```
class AbstractGamePosition(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def possible_actions(self):
      return
```

But here, I face a problem. Abstact class demands possible_actions method. In my concrete Position class, method that returns a set of all possible actions from is called unvisited_cities, because for the salesman problem only those cities can be the next targets that have not been visited yet. Is it possible to declare a Position as a child class of an AbstactGamePosition abstact class, and somehow let Python know that abstact method possible_actions is implemented in Position class by a concrete method unvisited_cities?

In naive language it could be something like this:

```
Position <- AbstactGamePosition:
   AbstactGamePosition.possible_actions = Position.unvisited_cities
```

However, Python does not have such a construction. Can this be somehow solved?

Obviously, this can be solved through an interface class:

```
class Interface(AbstactGamePosition):
   
   def __init__(self, position, concrete_method):
       self.position = position
       self._possible_actions = concrete_method
   
   def possible_actions(self):
       return self._possible_actions(self.position)

position = Position(salesman, cities)
interface = Interface(position, Position.unvisited_cities)
```

But this looks so sloppy that I find this disgusting.

Comment: To be clear, do you control the class `Position`, and can you change it? Or are you trying to leave the class definition for `Position` alone and get this to work?

Comment: And do control it, but I want to make my code related to monte calro tree search as abstact as I can. I want to be able to create many different classes like Position with different methods and than group them all into AbstactGamePosition class. I know the most simple solution is to call unvisited_cities method possible_actions, but is this the only way, thus?

Comment: If you have created a contract, and you want your derived class to implement that contract, then you need to modify the name of the function in the concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement the method by its expected and required name. You can call you *actual* implementation internally:

```
class Position(AbstractGamePosition):
    ...

    def unvisited_cities(self):
        ...
   
    def possible_actions(self):
        return self.unvisited_cities()
```

In fact, you can simply assign the `unvisited_cities` method to the required name, which has the same outcome:

```
class Position(AbstractGamePosition):
    ...

    def unvisited_cities(self):
        ...
   
    possible_actions = unvisited_cities
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the information in the comments (that you don't want to have a hard dependency between `Position` and `AbstractGamePosition`), I think you're looking for the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). Your `Interface` class is pretty close, though I agree that that level of reflection is unwarranted in this situation.

I would recommend created a small class alongside `Position` that is specifically *for* `position`, and that class can delegate to the original.

```
# (Type annotations provided for clarity; they are optional)
class PositionAdapter(AbstractGamePosition):

    def __init__(self, position: Position):
        self.position = position

    def possible_actions(self):
        return self.position.unvisited_cities()
```

Then, when you want to use a `Position` in a situation where an `AbstractGamePosition` is expected, you simply write

```
my_abstract_game_position = PositionAdapter(my_original_position)
```

and you can call `possible_actions` on `my_abstract_game_position`.

You will have to write one of these adapter classes for *each* class you want adapted to this abstract parent without a hard dependency. But it's not a lot of boilerplate (five lines of code, basically), so it's worth it if your goal is to keep all of these classes as loosely coupled as possible.

Comment: I see. I asked the question due to my haskell expirience. In haskell, Position would be a algebraic data type, and AbstactGamePosition would be a class. And my wish, would be implemented in the following construction: ''' Position is instance AbstractGamePosition where possible_actions = unvisited_cities'''

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, Python has no viable alternative to Haskell's typeclasses. The closest you can get is an adapter sort of pattern like the one I suggested here, but it still requires a decent bit of boilerplate. Scala has a nice middle ground in the form of context abstractions (`implicit` in Scala 2, `given` in Scala 3) that works with the OOP-style call syntax but still behaves like a typeclass. Rust pretty much just gives you typeclasses. Ruby has refinements nowadays that allow you to introduce instance methods in a given scope, which is close. But Python has no such machinery, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

`ABCMeta` *literally* only cares about the name being defined with an object that does not have an `__isabtractmethod__` attribute set to `True`: that's it.

You can patch `Position` with

```
Position.possible_actions = Position.unvisited_cites
```

then register `Position` as a subclass of the abstract base class.

```
AbstractGamePosition.register(Position)
```

(If fact, registering a virtual subclass doesn't even require the name to be properly defined; you can do so *without* defining `Position.possible_actions`.)

(Assuming you can't change the definition of `Position` to inherit from the abstract class. If you can, [@deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75138303/1126841) has you covered.)